# Dynamically move variable inner blocks to reduce parent block height

Tags: javascript, html, css, position

I am looking for a way to dynamically move child `<li>` blocks inside a `<ul>` list to take as little vertical space as possible. Here is an example:

[image]

I am sure that I've seen something similar years ago but can't find it now. I don't really want to reinvent the wheel, maybe someone could advice me on some existing solution? I don't need recommendations, just any script which can work for my case.

Comment: You might be looking for masonry? http://masonry.desandro.com/

Comment: @JoshC Must fit my needs, thank you for the quick response! :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to take as little vertical space as possible, you need JavaScript (e.g. masonry).

But you can approximate with CSS only solutions:

- Using `margin-right`: http://jsfiddle.net/VfYUY/
- Using `min-width`: http://jsfiddle.net/VfYUY/1/